# How to keep self cleaning oven from damaging things?

Tags: appliances, cabinets, oven

I would like to know some tips/opinions on the self cleaning function of an oven.

- Can it possibly hurt the oven's own circuitry?
- what is a good way from preventing surrounding from getting damaged (cabinets, micro, whatever)?  Last time I used it my cabinets fronts got scorched - turned them from white to light yellow.
- are there any settings on the oven that help for the self cleaning?

Comment: They definitely can damage the ovens own circuitry.  I have had to replace the entire control panel at the top after it melted.

Answer (score 1):

> what is a good way from preventing surrounding from getting damaged
>   (cabinets, micro, whatever)? Last time I used it my cabinets fronts
>   got scorched - turned them from white to light yellow.

To prevent the surroundings from getting damaged, I place two box window fans in front of the oven on the floor about 2 feet away, and table fan on the counter blowing behind.